# Writing my own MBR code to choose between systems

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, bootloader, mbr

I am trying to implement my own MBR code in order to let users choose which system to load. After I write it, I substitute the first nearly 200 bytes of the disk with my own code.
But I came across a problem that I cannot figure out, to load and execute the boot loader code of each system.

The code I wrote:

```
; Instruct NASM to generate code that is to be run on CPU that is running in 16 bit mode
bits 16

org 0x600

xor ax,ax
mov ss,ax
mov sp,0x7c00
sti
push ax
pop es
push ax
pop ds
cld
mov si,0x7c1b
mov di,0x61b
push ax
push di
mov cx,0x1e5
rep movsb
retf
mov bp,0x7be


; choose_background:
    mov ah, 0x06    ; Clear / scroll screen up function
    xor al, al      ; Number of lines by which to scroll up (00h = clear entire window)
    xor cx, cx      ; Row,column of window's upper left corner
    mov dx, 0x184f  ; Row,column of window's lower right corner
    mov bh, 0xf1    ; Background/foreground colour. In our case - red background / yellow foreground (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_color_attributes)
    int 0x10        ; Issue BIOS video services interrupt with function 0x06

    ; Move label's bootloaderBanner memory address to si
    mov si, bootloaderBanner
    ; Put 0x0e to ah, which stands for "Write Character in TTY mode" when issuing a BIOS Video Services interrupt 0x10
    mov ah, 0x0e
    loop:
        ; Load byte at address si to al
        lodsb
        ; Check if al==0 / a NULL byte, meaning end of a C string
        test al, al
        ; If al==0, jump to end, where the bootloader will be halted
        jz exit_print_loop
        ; Issue a BIOS interrupt 0x10 for video services
        int 0x10                                                
        ; Repeat
        jmp loop
    exit_print_loop:
        ; Clear the keyboard buffer
    xor ah, ah
    ; Read a character from the keyboard
    mov ah, 0
    int 0x16

    ; Display the character on the screen
    mov ah, 0x0e
    int 0x10
    ; mov ah, 0
    ; int 0x16

    cmp al, '1'
    jne start_ubuntu

    mov ax,0x201
    mov bx,0x7c00
    mov cx,[bp+0x2]
    mov dx,[bp+0x0]
    int 0x13
    jnc 0x7c00 

    start_ubuntu:
        xor ax,ax
        mov ds,ax
        mov si,0x7c05

        mov byte [si],0x10
        mov byte [si+0x1],0x00
        mov byte [si+0x2],0x01
        mov byte [si+0x3],0x00
        mov byte [si+0x4],0x00
        mov byte [si+0x5],0x80
        mov byte [si+0x6],0x00
        mov byte [si+0x7],0x00
        mov byte [si+0x8],0x01
        mov byte [si+0x9],0x00
        mov byte [si+0xa],0x00
        mov byte [si+0xb],0x00
        mov byte [si+0xc],0x00
        mov byte [si+0xd],0x00
        mov byte [si+0xe],0x00
        mov byte [si+0xf],0x00

        mov ah,0x42
        mov dl,0x80

        int 0x13
        jnc 0x8000

    bootloaderBanner: db "                                  1 Windows",13,10,"                                  2 Ubuntu",13,10, 0

; Fill remaining space of the 512 bytes minus our instructions, with 00 bytes
; $ - address of the current instruction
; $$ - address of the start of the image .text section we're executing this code in
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
; Bootloader magic number
dw 0xaa55
```

And i copied the valid binary code into the first nearly 200 bytes of the disk and did not change the rest part like partition table

Part of the partition table of my disk is:

| B | SCHS | ID | ECHS | RSLBA | SecCnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | 20 21 00 | 07 | df 13 0c | 00 08 00 00 | 00 20 03 00 |
| 00 | df 14 0c | 07 | fe ff ff | 00 28 03 00 | 00 98 d1 01 |
| 00 | fe ff ff | 05 | fe ff ff | fe c7 d4 01 | 02 30 4b 01 |
| 00 | 00.... |  |  |  |  |

By the way, my computer system is MSWindows 11 and the virtual disk is created by qemu. And the systems I installed are MSWindows 7 and Ubuntu 22.04

Now I wonder where the stage 2 of ubuntu is located. I searched online and from [this](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GRUB.htm) i know i need to find the **(4-byte) Quad-Word**, but i never know where it is. I have also searched the string *"Loading stage2"* in the whole disk but no results.

The result of `fdisk -l` in the ubuntu system installed on the disk:

| equipment | start | beginning | end | sector | size | id | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/sda1 |  | 2048 | 206847 | 204800 | 100M | 7 | HPFS/NTFS/exFAT |
| /dev/sda2 |  | 206848 | 30719999 | 30513152 | 14.5G | 7 | HPFS/NTFS/exFAT |
| /dev/sda3 |  | 30722046 | 52426751 | 21704706 | 10.3G | 5 | extend |
| /dev/sda5 | * | 30722048 | 31111167 | 389120 | 190M | ef | EFI(FAT -12/16/32) |
| /dev/sda6 |  | 31113216 | 52426751 | 21313536 | 10.2G | 83 | Linux |

Comment: You need to use SCHS ("Start CHS"), not ECHS ("End CHS"). Or, calculate the CHS tuple from the Start LBA sector number. Or, in case it is supported for this unit, use the LBA read function 42h. The ECHS with `fe ff ff` further is most likely invalid, a placeholder value for a too large sector number. Moreover, you cannot load boot sector loaders (read from the Partition Boot Records) to addresses like 0:8000h or 0:2000h and expect them to work. You'll have to relocate your loader (eg to 0:600h) and then load to 0:7C00h. Example: https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldosmbr/file/a0b0648732c8/oldmbr.asm

Comment: @ecm I have tried to relocate my order to 0:600h by adding the following code in front of my code.

`   section .text
  cpu 8086
  org 0600h

_start:  cli
  xor ax,ax
  mov ds,ax
  mov es,ax
  mov ss,ax
  mov sp,7C00h
  sti
  cld
  mov si,sp  ; Start address
  mov di,0600h  ; Destination address
  mov cx,512/2
  rep movsw

;
;jump to the copy at 0600h 
  jmp 0:600h  
`
But the program is stuck in "Boot from hard disk". Can you tell me how to figure it out? To be honest, I am not so familiar with assembly. I would appreciate it if you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Please do not post long code blocks in comments, edit your question instead. Anyway, `jmp 0:600h` is wrong because it will simply re-enter your code at the beginning. So that gives an infinite loop. In lDOS oldmbr, we have `jmp 0:next ; Jump to copy at 0600h` which along with `org 600h` jumps to a subsequent entrypoint, not the beginning at 600h.

Comment: @ecm I am sorry .This is the first time i use stackoverflow. I will not do this again. And I have edited my question, can you help me out of that ?

Comment: Does it work if you mark the Ubuntu partition as inactive (first byte of partition table entry = 0) and the MSWindows partition as active (80h)? Just guessing, I've seen code from Microsoft expecting to load off an active primary partition. You may also want to make sure that `ss:bp` and `ds:si` both point to the partition entry to boot in the MBR copy at 0:600h. (PS. The MBR is only at sector zero of the entire unit, the other boot sectors are called Partition Boot Records or PBRs, or simply boot sectors.)

Comment: @ecm I have tried to change the active byte but nothing changes. And i don't understand how to change the `ss:bp` and `ds:si` and why they should be adjusted.  I would appreciate it if you can help me out of it.

Comment: @ecm I have tried to recover the original MBR and it worked quite well. Seems like i have done something wrong when loading the PBR. Moreover, I am wondering the correct PBR to load is in the system-reserved-partition or in the second partition with 10G that i am using now. I have searched a lot but no good answers.

Comment: Just a note - your CHS (Cylinder/Head/Sector) values are not in the correct order. IE: `df 14 0c` is actually Heads/Sectors/Cylinders.

Comment: You want to read the PBR (Usually referred to as the VBR) from CHS=(0x00, 0x20, 0x21). That is the first Sector of the system reserved partition. When the PBR runs it will then load the next 15 Sectors after the PBR into memory starting at 0x7e00. Those 15 sectors are often referred to as the BOOTMGR Loader. It's job is to find the bootmgr file in the partition marked active.

Comment: I wonder if the problem here is that your master boot record (MBR) doesn't have a proper partition table set up in it (with exactly 1 active partition). I'm going to assume the original MBR had a partition table. Usually the partition table starts at offset 0x1be. Each entry is 16 bytes. There are 4 entries, thus the partition table is exactly 64 bytes. This 64 bytes also happens to be immediately before the 0xaa55  disk signature at the end. See this for MBR/Partition Table info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record

Comment: I'd recommend copying the 64 byte partition table from the original MBR into your MBR placing it just before the 0xaa55 at the end.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The CHS values are given in the same order and packed way as they occur in the partition table, in which the first byte is H (to `dh`), the second byte is S in the low 6 bits and C in the high 2 bits (to `cl`) and the third byte is C low 8 bits (to `ch`).

Comment: @ecm : Yes, I know that but when he created his chart for the question he made it ambiguous given the title of each column. It does of course match the partition table entries ordering and packing. Some who read the question may have to do a double take looking at the chart. As I pointed out - it was just a "note"

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have completed my partition table in the problem.  Did you mean i should load the first sector of system reserved partition (0x00, 0x20, 0x21) into memory instead of the first sector of the second partition and mark the second sector as active(0x80)?

Comment: Your first partition is the 100MiB system reserved partition (the one with SCHS = 20 21 00) and it should be the only one marked active. You should be reading the PBR from the reserved partition at SCHS = 20 21 00.

Comment: This is beyond what you need to know but once the entire BOOTMGR is in memory it is launched and it then consults the file \boot\BCD in the system reserved partition to determine which Windows partition to boot (I assume in your case is the second partition SCHS = df 14 0c). Which windows partition to boot can be modified inside Windows using the `dskmgmt` tool (GUI). There is another Windows tool called `BCDEDIT.EXE` that can manipulate the BCD store as well. BCD=Boot configuration data

Comment: I'm also going to recommend that instead of int 0x13/ah=0x02 to read disk sectors using CHS addressing that you switch over to using int 0x13/ah=0x42 LBA addressing for non-floppy media. This way you can read beyond C=1023 H=255 S=63 (and support disks larger than 8455716864 bytes). It is clear from your partitioning that your disk is larger than that.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for your help and I have loaded the windows system correctly. But I came into problem when i tried to find the stage of ubuntu. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Looking at your code, did you also add a partition table at the end? I don't see how those code would have found Windows without the partition table? Or do you use a tool to add the partition table after creating the MBR binary? You have a number of issues one of which is that you'll have to use extended disk reads (int 0x13/ah=0x42) using LBA rather than CHS addressing. The second problem (and this is a big one) - it appears you placed your Linux boot partition and your Linux distro inside an extended disk partition?

Comment: May I ask... is there a reason you don't use GRUB to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu or is there a reason you are writing your own bootloader to do this?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Actually this is a programmimg assignment from my professor. Unfortunately, students taking this class are not equipped with pre-knowledge and to be honest, there is no clear description. Therefore different students install different systems. And my professor ask us to search and ask online to look for help.  (Also i get help from my professor).

Comment: @MichaelPetch Actually I copy my code to the first bytes of disk, and the partition table in the original mbr of the disk are not modified. Besides I followed the instructions of ubuntu to install it and it ends up that there is an extended disk partition. I don't know where the stage 2 of unubtu is located.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The TA tells us it is usually located in the sector 1 and if not, we should figure the place out. I searched online and from [this](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GRUB.htm) i know i need to find the **(4-byte) Quad-Word**, but i never know where it is. I have also searched the string _"Loading stage2"_ in the whole disk but no results.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I also wonder that if I have installed a higher version of ubuntu or GRUB. And if I install a lower version of ubuntu like ubuntu 18.04, will the ubuntu stage2 be located in the sector1?

Comment: This is well beyond the scope of Stack overflow. I think you are going to have to talk to your professor or TA. I can't tell you where Linux is installed because it is hidden inside the extended boot record (third partition showing type 5). Where GRUB's stage 2 is placed is dependent on how you installed Ubuntu. It could have been the first 63 Secord's of the disk or the partition the Ubuntu boot partitions was in. If you installed GRUB at the beginning of the disk when installing Ubuntu and then you install Windows - Windows will overwrite GRUB's MBR.

Comment: If you run Linux's `sfdisk` on the disk image you are using with QEMU, can you provide the output in the question for this command  `sfdisk disk.img` where disk.img is the name of your disk image file? It should tell you what is inside the extended partition

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have used the command `fdisk` on the ubuntu system installed on the disk and got the chart int the problem. I am not sure whether it is what you need. Since my computer system is windows11,  I am still learning how to use `sfdisk` in my system.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Moreover I install windows first and then ubuntu

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have completed the project. Thanks for your help !